# If the square of an integer is odd, then the integer is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

The statement is: If the square of the integer x is odd, then x is odd.

My textbook says an indirect proof is applicable here but I came up with the following:

1. State that If $x^2$ is odd, then $x$ is odd.
2. Next, we assume that $x$ is odd.
3. We know if $x$ is an integer, then $x = 2k+1$ given some integer $k$.
4. This gives us $x^2 = 2k+1$
5. $(2k+1)^2 = 2k+1$
6. We know that the square of an odd integer is odd and that $2k+1$ is odd because $k$ is an integer. Therefore, QED.

Have I overlooked something? Can this be performed with a direct proof somehow?

Comment: Part 1 seems strange. In part 2, you assume what you would like to show. In part 5 you reuse $k$ for some reason to get an equation with no solutions in the integers. In part 6 you state that this finishes the proof even though there does not seem to be any connection to the above.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Looks like my mind is way off then... :) If I were to solve this directly (or attempt to..) would I have to assume that x^2 is odd, then? I want to lead into that x is odd, right? So would I start by doing something similar and then just replacing x^2 instead?

Comment: You just sketched (poorly on line 5) a proof that $x$ odd $\Rightarrow$ $x^2$ odd. You are supposed to be proving the other direction, $x^2$ odd $\Rightarrow$ $x$ odd. The textbook is right, the indirect proof is applicable, that is, prove the contrapositive.

Comment: @J.W.Perry Thanks for the tip. Any advice on how to pre-emptively identify that I should use an indirect instead of misleading myself into a direct proof trap?

Comment: @VaughanHilts This is just a matter of developing your intuition, and being willing to try some approaches that don't work before settling on one that does (and being able to recognize when something isn't working). Good mathematicians don't necessarily know the right way to solve a problem the first time they try it; they're just willing to give it as many tries as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct proof has to start with you assuming $x^2$ is odd, then proving $x$ must be odd. You have sort of assumed that both $x$ and $x^2$ are odd, and then shown that 'nothing bad happens' which is not a rigorous proof.

An indirect proof (via contrapositive) will probably be easier. Note that in this case, the contrapositive is

"if $x$ is not odd, then the square of $x$ is not odd"

i.e.

"if $x$ is even, then the square of $x$ is even".

You can then use the same ideas, i.e. you can say "if $x$ is even, then $x = 2k$ for some integer $k$..."

then you have to show that, if you take $x^2$, there is some *other* integer $m$ so that $x^2 = 2m$.

You should try to figure out what $m$ is on your own, but if you are still stuck after some effort,

> $m = 2k^2$

Comment: Even better proof: $x (x+1) = x^2 + x$. Since the left-hand side is even, the terms on the right-hand side have the same parity.

Answer (score 0):

In your step 2, you assume $x$ is odd.  But that is the very thing to be proved.  You set out to prove that if $x^2$ is odd then $x$ is odd, not that if $x$ is odd, then $x^2$ is odd.

You said $x=2k+1$, and that that gives us $x^2=2k+1$.  That is not correct.  If $x=2k+1$, then $x^2=4k^2+4k+1$.  Nor is it true that $(2k+1)^2=2k+1$, as asserted in your step 5.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above all in that the book's approach for indirect, i.e. here the best one being the contrapositive, as the other two options left out for the same (as per my knowledge, are the inverse and the converse), and that yields very quickly and easily too.

But, regarding the direct proof I think some effort should be made too. 
 WLOG, can assume that the integer is positive,
If $\exists k, k' \in \mathbb{Z+}, \,k'\mid 2,\,x^2\,=\,2k+1\,=\,(k'+1)^2$, then $x'=k'+1$.

I am not clear if the proof is rigorous enough, but it seems simple enough to raise concern.